# How to send a GET request with JSON body in JMeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, request, get

I am facing some issues as JMeter doesn't take the JSON body passed as a parameter. I tried through postman and it was working fine but for Jmeter it is not working

I am expecting a response from get request with JSON body in Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

We're not telepathic enough in order to suggest you how you can fix your "some issues" without knowing the details of the "issues"

JMeter can send the GET request with the JSON (or any other) body

[image]

If the request works in Postman and doesn't in JMeter most probably you're not sending the same requests, the most common mistake is that people forget to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) configured to send correct [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header.

Just use a 3rd-party [sniffer tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) to intercept requests originating from JMeter or Postman, identify the difference(s) and amend your JMeter configuration so the requests would be exactly the same. Alternatively just record the request from Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

Comment: i have included the json parameter in the body of the http request as this 

{"PageNumber":1,"PageSize":2000}

But as i make request i am getting error and GET data don't have any JSON parameters, 

GET data:
[no cookies]